# Forced to use too many hidden fields; looking for an alternative approach

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am looking for a better approach to do this.

I have around 70 to 80 hidden fields in my page. This hidden fields are initialized at the server side and then used at the client side for validations, calculations, etc,. using java script.

I wanted to know if there is any other alternative approach to using hidden fields in asp.net. I guess, these many hidden fields are increasing the page size and hence affecting the performance of my web page and I want to do away with it.

FYI: I am working on an asp.net web application.

Answer (score 1):

validations, calculations using javascript are better done when taking JSON as base data.
Just assign to a JS variable a JSON generated server-side, then use it in your JS as an object or array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying this and get back if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest that you describe the information as a data structure, serialize it to [JSON](http://json.org), include it in a `<script>` element (assigned to a variable you can access with your validation code).

… but you'd still be getting the data to the client, so the performance issues don't really go away.

You could look at providing it in an external file, so it can be cached, but I don't know enough about how reusable the data is to say if that is feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying this and get back if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the head of your HTML add some javascript initializing variables with the data you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var option1 = true;
    var option2 = 'some text';
    ...
</script>
```

You can then access these variables for your javascript validations.

Comment: This would improve performance, as you would no longer be submitting all those hidden fields.

Comment: I don't think this is possible as my values get initialized from the server side code.

Comment: At the time you serve the page, define these variables in the head of your page.  They are then available to js on the browser.

Another option is to serve up an asp page as js.  I work in PHP & Ruby so I can't give you the exact code, but in PHP, we name the file script.js.php, and then define the document header to be of type "text/javascript".  You could then use server logic to set page/user specific variables in your js page.

Two gotchas in this last option.  It may mess with cacheing in Opera. And in some CMS's (like WordPress), CMS specific functions may not be included.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the JSON and JS data ideas promoted here - you'd be sending down the information needed for your calcs and validation in a lean format, and it wouldn't be posted back.

This provides a direct means to access your data, rather than some jQuery/DOM search to get your hidden field values, boosting the performance of calcs.

If you're talking about performance in terms of download and render time, and if the JSON representation of your client-side data is huge, then your only other option is making AJAX calls to do the calcs and validations server side, so that your large dataset never travels down the wire in either direction. Be wary though about the AJAX roundtrip time to get an answer back to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying this and get back if needed.